# LinearLayout - Have the image stretched but the text centered too?

Tags: android, image, listview, layout, textview

I am trying to customize my settings app by adding in a variation of the Google Cards. I have images on the left of my list item and then text on the right. Right now the issue I face is that my images get fully stretched to the height and width I want but then my textview also get stretched and get off aligned and now sits on the top corner right beside the image. I wanted a gap between the image and the text and I want the text to be centered and not located on the top left.. Here is my layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minHeight="48dp"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Settings.Main"
android:background="@drawable/background_list_view"
android:divider="@color/list_divider"
android:dividerHeight="@dimen/list_divider"
android:gravity="fill"
android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dip"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/header_icon_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_icon_width"
        android:layout_gravity="fill" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My background_list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
     android:state_focused="true"
     android:state_pressed="true"
     android:drawable="@drawable/list_longpressed_holo_light" />
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused_holo" />
<item
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed_holo_light" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_normal_holo_light" />
```

Here is a screenshot of what I have at the moment:

[image]

As you can see the text is located in the top near the image, what I want is a bit of gap between them to seperate it a bit and to have in the center as well.

Comment: Sorry, there shoudln't be a textview above imageview in layout.xml since it causes the app to crash.

Comment: No, it won't cause crashes on your app. It's a Lint warning, you are advised to use a Compound Drawable TextView. But that's up to you whether to use it or keep the layout as it is.

Comment: Well, I changed my layout, updated the drawable file and layout but the text still is in top left..you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what you want. You want the image stretched and have a gap between image and text? If the image is stretched, why don't you just set the image as background of the TextView? Would be great if you can share us your currently and desired result in pics.

Comment: Hope that helps, I think the screen will show whats wrong and then the description below of what I want should give clear idea on what I need, Thanks Aprian for trying to help me out here!

Comment: Anyone else? The text is still a bit off from center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically your first layout, should work great. Otherwise, please tell me what's going wrong.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/header_icon_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_icon_width"
        android:layout_gravity="fill" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well the code worked, it didn't give crashes like when I tried to put a TextView in and the space I wanted also worked but the text is still  like that..can it be the conflicted gravity making it non-centered. Edit: I am testing, out a variation of your code to see if it works.

Comment: Weird, the text is showing correctly in my place. You can try to change `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and add `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to the `@+id/text`. You can remove `layout_gravity` as well.

Comment: I will try that, but with your code the text is actually centered but off by a bit. It isn't at the top anymore, lemme try that. Thanks

Comment: No, it didn't work, still the same http://imgur.com/kfjJwAd The text is just a bit off center as you can see but its coming together ;)

Comment: Probably cause by padding or margin. Maybe you could change the background for `@+id/text` and `@+id/title` to different colors and see what caused the problem.

Comment: Tried to remove id/title didn't fix anything. I don't see how changing bg colors will help though.